# Composition of three functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $f:W\rightarrow X$, $g:X\rightarrow Y$, and $h:Y\rightarrow Z$, does $h \circ (g \circ f) = (h \circ g) \circ f$? How can I justify this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean with "does h(g(x)) of f = h(g(f(x))"?

Comment: is h o (g o f) = (h o g) o f    Does that explain it?

Comment: Do you mean to ask why is $h\circ(g\circ f)=(h\circ g)\circ f$?

Comment: The answer to the question in the comments is "yes".

Comment: Yes - to henning makholm. I just could not figure out how to format that as a question. Vadim123, can you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $w\in W$ we have
$$ [h\circ (g\circ f)](w) = h([g\circ f](w)) = h(g(f(w)) $$
and
$$ [(h\circ g)\circ f](w) = [h\circ g](f(w)) = h(g(f(w)) $$

Since $h\circ (g\circ f)$ and $(h\circ g)\circ f$ have the same value at every possible argument, they are the same function.

Comment: and since they have the same domain and codomain (trivial remark, but the question is trivial anyway)